# How to read page source code using urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read the page source code of web pages hosted by a Content Management System (CMS).

To view the web pages via browser, I type in the URL, input my username and password (to authenticate to the domain (intranet)). When I right-click the webpage > View source code, I get all the page content within  tags. The page contains many h1, h2, p and table tags.

I want to run a script to get the page source code. When I execute the below code, I don’t get the complete page source code (within the  tags).

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser

testlink = 'mylinkwithinCMS'

auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',uri='mydomain', user='myusername', passwd='mypassword')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen(testlink)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

I get only a single line of code which looks like this:

```
<body><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"0f4bf752fg”,”applicationID":"135707588”,”transactionName":"ZwZaYBQFXktSVhBZDl5MbUYPS1NXQVBAgFIFkNdFA==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":270,"atts":"S0FZFlwfTUU=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script></body>
```

Comment: Hello @DInfo2019. Could you explain the test case used, the result you obtain and what you expect ?

Comment: Thank you Bertrand. I have modified my question now. Please let me know if this helps.